# Installation and usage of 'make htmldocs'

Tags: linux, restructuredtext, rst2html.py

I want to convert Linux kernel rst files to html document.
Please provide clear steps to install the required packages and commands to generate rst file to html.

I have installed sphinx with below command

```
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

Facing an error when I run 'make htmldocs'

```
The Sphinx 'sphinx_rtd_theme' HTML theme was not found
```

If possible, could you please help me with right packages to install?
It looks like tricky and I have tried enough.

Answer (score 2):

I just have figured it out that there is a document in the Linux kernel which explains the required information to use 'make pdfdocs':

```
Reference: Documentation/doc-guide/sphinx.rst

#sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
#sudo apt-get install python-sphinx-rtd-theme
#sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
#sudo apt-get install texlive-base
#sudo apt-get install graphviz
#sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Run below commands from kernel root directory

```
#/usr/bin/virtualenv ~/sphinx_1.4
#. ~/sphinx_1.4/bin/activate
#pip install -r Documentation/sphinx/requirements.txt
#make htmldocs
```

Generated html documents are located at Documents/output